# WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available

Tags: kali-linux, python, ssl, pip

I'm using Kali Linux 2020.1, I installed Python3.7, then after trying to install modules using pip3 command I keep getting this error message.

```
  WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: none)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for flask

    Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Comment: Check the openssl version, probably you need update this.

Answer (score 4):

To do we must compile it and install each dependency

- Download if need  https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tar.x
- Unpack file

  ```
  tar zxvf Python-3.7.0.tar.gz --directory /tmp
  cd /tmp
  ```
- Edit file `Setup.dist` to enabled SSL

  ```
  cd Python-3.7.0/Modules/
  vi Setup.dist
  ```
- un-comment following line and update `openssl` home

  ```
  SSL=/usr/local/ssl  <--- substitute with your openssl home directory
  _ssl _ssl.c \
          -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
          -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
  ```
- save and compile python for distribution

  ```
  cd ../
  ./configure --enable-optimizations CFLAGS="-O3" --prefix=/opt/primeur/python3.7
  make
  make install
  ```
- Try it

  ```
  cd /opt/primeur/python3.7/bin
  [root@myserver bin]# python3

  Python 3.7.0 (default, May 5 2020, 22:31:07)

  [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux

  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>>
  ```
- update `pip` with command

  ```
  [root@myserver bin]#./pip3 install --upgrade pip
  ```
- install any dependency using `pip3 install` like

  ```
  [root@myserver bin]#./pip3 install termcolor

  Collecting termcolor
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/48/a76be51647d0eb9f10e2a4511bf3ffb8cc1e6b14e9e4fab46173aa79f981/termcolor-1.1.0.tar.gz
  Installing collected packages: termcolor
  Running setup.py install for termcolor ... done
  Successfully installed termcolor-1.1.0
  ```

Comment: It's unusual to install any python module this way.  Could you explain why it needs to be built from source rather than installing via one of the mainstream channels?  eg: install using apt

Comment: because I install on RedHat without YUM

Comment: This question is about installing on Kali Linux which *does have* apt.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may have inadvertently installed without something it needs.  The error looks similar to one generated by the [python requests library](https://pypi.org/project/requests/).

I would check this is properly installed and it's dependencies are met.  I notice that `python-openssl` is only a suggested package and not a required one. You might want to see if installing this one helps.

```
Package: python3-requests
Depends: python3-certifi, python3-chardet (<< 3.1.0), python3-idna, python3-urllib3 (<< 1.26), python3:any, ca-certificates, python3-chardet (>= 3.0.2), python3-urllib3 (>= 1.21.1)
Suggests: python3-cryptography, python3-idna (>= 2.5), python3-openssl, python3-socks, python-requests-doc
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked very well for me:

[SSL issues with Python 3.7 Install From Source](https://joshspicer.com/python37-ssl-issue)

Thanks Josh.

I make a summary of the procedure:

---

**Steps**

I decided to just install openSSL again by pulling down the newest version of the source code.

```
sudo apt-get install -y wget
mkdir /tmp/openssl
cd /tmp/openssl
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2q.tar.gz
tar xvf openssl-1.0.2q.tar.gz
cd /tmp/openssl/openssl-1.0.2q
./config
make
sudo make install
```

The key here (and the reason i’m writing this post) is to show how to tell Python where this new installation of openSSL is. By default your manual install of openSSL will be in `/usr/local/ssl`. You can confirm this by checking the modify time of the ssl directory with `ls -la /usr/local/ssl`.

By default, Python isn’t going to look here. We need to fix that. To begin, run the first part of the Python install script (as seen below).

```
# Install requirements
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
sudo apt-get install -y checkinstall
sudo apt-get install -y libreadline-gplv2-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libncursesw5-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libsqlite3-dev
sudo apt-get install -y tk-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libgdbm-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libc6-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libbz2-dev
sudo apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install -y openssl
sudo apt-get install -y libffi-dev
sudo apt-get install -y python3-dev
sudo apt-get install -y python3-setuptools
sudo apt-get install -y wget
# Prepare to build
mkdir /tmp/Python37
cd /tmp/Python37
# Pull down Python 3.7, build, and install
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
tar xvf Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
```

Now STOP, cd to `/tmp/Python37/Python-3.7.0` and open up the file `Modules/Setup.dist`

You should see the following lines COMMENTED.

```
# Socket module helper for SSL support; you must comment out the other
# socket line above, and possibly edit the SSL variable:
SSL=/usr/local/ssl
 _ssl _ssl.c \
    -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
    -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

What you need to do is UNCOMMENT these lines so that they are seen during our Python compile. Now you can finish up by running that last few lines of our python script.

```
cd /tmp/Python37/Python-3.7.0
./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
```

At this point I now had a working python and pip (mapped to python3.7 and pip3.7 in my path).

Comment: I redid something similar with Python 3.10 and CentOS 7, tried to update PIP: `/usr/local/bin/python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip` 
 but the PIP update didn't work: 
`WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(0, 'unknown error (_ssl.c:4111)'))': /simple/pip/`

Comment: +1; This answer is very helpful, as it helped me understand the point of sp ecifying openssl directory path (as I had multiple versions on a legacy system) while doing python make.

Answer (score 0):

If you have compiles the Python, then do the following thing to get SSL enabled in the Python.

```
mkdir /home/$USER/tools
export INSTALL_BASE_PATH=/home/$USER/tools

mkdir -p {INSTALL_BASE_PATH}/ssl
vi Python-3.9.10/Modules/Setup      # Modify below lines in this file to these

SSL={INSTALL_BASE_PATH}/ssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
        -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
        -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto


./configure \
    --prefix=${INSTALL_BASE_PATH} \
    --enable-shared \
    --enable-ipv6 \
    LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=${INSTALL_BASE_PATH}/lib,--disable-new-dtags

make
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install Python 3.11.4 from the source on a Ubuntu 18.04-based PYNQ system. All dependencies are installed and I encountered the same problem above.

It turns out to be an OpenSSL version problem.

- The `openssl` version in apt source is 1.1.0g.
- After installing [`libssl`](https://pkgs.org/download/libssl1.1), [`libssl-dev`](https://pkgs.org/download/libssl-dev), [`openssl`](https://pkgs.org/download/openssl) with version 1.1.1, the problem is solved.